# jwplayer - get time watched - pay per minute - do action on time

Tags: javascript, jquery, streaming, jwplayer

I'm trying to get the time duration someone watched a video, or even better do an action each minute. What I'm trying to do is a sort of pay per minute solution. Each minute there has to be a credit withdrawal from the user.

If this isn't possible how can I set a maximum amount of minutes the video is watchable, depending on the amount of credits the user has?

I have a licensed jw player which is non editable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a javascript setInterval function.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function to deduct a point
}, 60000);
```

Comment: Wouldn't the onTime() function from jwplayer be more suitable? Because I only want to deduct a point each minute the video is being played. With setInterval even if the video is on pause it would deduct points... Are there better solutions to this?

Comment: @user3674217 you could have a set interval every second and check if the video is playing, then if it is add 1/60 of a point

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you will need to integrate this with your existing users' database to check who is who and how much time he paid and consumed. If I'm right, then why don't you implement this on server side? Depending on media streaming solution which you use, you could build that part on server side and you wouldn't be reliable on player implementation.

I love JWPlayer and I respect Jeroen Wijering personally (I even talked to him several times on conferences), but you need to select more proper toolset for this kind of task.

Let me know which media server you use.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answers guys. My current solution is something like this: In the onTime function I check if the Math.floor(event.position) is different, if so I increment the counter. Once the counter hits 60 I run an ajax post to a PHP script with the current user ID where I change the user credits.

```
onTime: function(event) {
            var time = Math.floor(event.position);
            if(time != old_time){
                counter++;
                old_time = time;
            }
            if(counter == 60) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'streaming_services.php',
                    data: {functionname: 'continuePlaying', id: <?php echo $_SESSION['wp_wallet_user_id']; ?>}, 
                     success:function(result) {                   
                         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                         $( "span#wallet_stats span" ).text( obj.credits );
                         if(obj.credits <= 0) {
                             jwplayer('player').remove();
                         }
                     },
                    error:function(data) {
                        console.log("error");
                     }
                });
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
```

If there is a better solution, or my code isn't optimized let me know! I'm still learning so I really appreciate any help. @Aquary @EthanJWPlayer

Answer (score 0):

You could use our API and the onTime() event - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference